# How does Kafka guarantee sequential disk access?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm a newbie for Kafka. When I read the documentation of Kafka, I saw that [Kafka is performing well because of sequential disk access](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#persistence).

But how is that possible? In Java(or something else), If I use File I/O, OS will handle it appropriately. However, I can't know if OS store the files I want to store in multiple sectors or in contiguous sectors. So, Kafka cannot always say that sequential disk access occurs in my opinion.

Am I true or not?

Comment: Read this - https://www.quora.com/Kafka-writes-every-message-to-broker-disk-Still-performance-wise-it-is-better-than-some-of-the-in-memory-message-storing-message-queues-Why-is-that

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Kafka does not **always** access disk sequentially but it does some things that make it much more likely that disk access is **often** sequential. All Kafka messages are stored in larger segment files (1GB each by default) and since Kafka messages are not deleted when consumed (like in other message brokers) Kafka will not end up creating a fragmented filesystem over time by continuously creating and deleting many variable length files. Instead it creates segment files and then appends to that file until it reaches 1GB (a configurable limit). Only when all messages in the segment expire will it delete the entire 1GB segment. This means that often these 1GB sections of disk are actually laid out as contiguous blocks. It is a recommended best practice to keep these Kafka commit log files on a dedicated filesystem so it does not get fragmented by other apps reading and writing variable length files into the same filesystem. More importantly most reading an writing to these segment files is sequential and goes through OS page cache so as to reduce disk I/O even further by caching the most often accessed pages in memory. This is why it is a recommendation to tune the kernel to set swappiness to 1 to reduce the likelihood that these cached pages would get swapped out of memory.

Comment: So if I apply 1GB disk in advance with normal api, then write to this part of the disk, it will also be sequential, is that correct?

Comment: Perhaps read through the section entitled "Don't fear the filesystem!" from the Apache Kafka design doc here https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/kafka/site/082/design.html